# Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY

Tags: magento-1.9, database, collection

```
public function getStatusLimit($array = array()) {
    $this->getSelect()->reset()
        ->union(
            $array
        );

    return $this;
}
```

---

```
$this->_collection->getStatusLimit(array($this->getCollection1()->getSelect(),$this->getCollection2()->getSelect()));
```

result of query

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM gn_daily_bidding_history WHERE gn_daily_bidding_history.msisdn_id = main_table.msisdn_id) AS `total_bids`, (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(customer_id)) FROM gn_daily_bidding_history WHERE gn_daily_bidding_history.msisdn_id = main_table.msisdn_id) AS `total_bidders` FROM `gn_msisdn_bid_list` AS `main_table` WHERE (cat_id = '3') AND (msisdn_status = '1') AND (bid_start <= '2016-07-12 04:50:30') AND (bid_status != 1) AND (bid_status = 2) AND (bid_end >= '2016-07-12 04:50:30') ORDER BY `main_table`.`bid_end` desc
```

UNION

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM gn_daily_bidding_history WHERE gn_daily_bidding_history.msisdn_id = main_table.msisdn_id) AS `total_bids`, (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(customer_id)) FROM gn_daily_bidding_history WHERE gn_daily_bidding_history.msisdn_id = main_table.msisdn_id) AS `total_bidders` FROM `gn_msisdn_bid_list` AS `main_table` WHERE (cat_id = '3') AND (msisdn_status = '1') AND (bid_start <= '2016-07-12 04:50:30') AND (bid_status = 3) AND (bid_end <= '2016-07-12 04:50:30') ORDER BY `main_table`.`bid_end` desc
```

not wrapping with query with "()"

Comment: i want this query like (select ....) union (select ....)

Comment: Consult core files, you will get an idea. As per as above answer, it can be handled. Please see the below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205610/why-is-union-all-with-and-without-parenthesis-behaving-different Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `Zend_Db_Select::SQL_UNION_ALL`

```
public function getStatusLimit($array = array()) {
    $this->getSelect()->reset()
        ->union(
            $array, Zend_Db_Select::SQL_UNION_ALL
        );

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: i also use with concate like $this->_collection->getStatusLimit(array('('. $this->getCollection1()->getSelect(). ')', '('. $this->getCollection2()->getSelect()->limit(3). ')'));